# Drupal 8 POST /user/login?_format=json 500 (500 Service unavailable (with message))

Tags: json, rest, fetch, drupal-8

I am trying to get a simple user login to work using fetch POST in a ReactJS app against Drupal 8.8 Rest endpoint so I can POST with CSRF or other methods. If I issue the following with a CURL request:

```
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST   --data '{"name":"myname", "pass":"mypassword123"}' http://example.com/user/login?_format=json
```

... I get ...

```
    {"current_user":{"uid":"1","roles":["authenticated","administrator"],"name":"myname"},"csrf_token":"xxxxx","logout_token":"xxxx"}
```

In my application on the other hand I use a fetch request...

```
 _handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(
      "http://example.com/user/login?_format_json",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: {
          data: {
            user: "myname",
            pass: "mypassword123"
          }
        }
      }
    );
```

I get

Drupal 8 POST /user/login?_format=json 500 (500 Service unavailable (with message))

I've also tried removing the "body" key like so:

```
  _handleSubmit = async event => {
event.preventDefault();
const response = await fetch(
  "http://example.com/entity/user?_format_json",
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
      data: {
        user: "myname",
        pass: "mypassword123"
      }
  }
);
```

... also, I have REST UI module but there is no endpoint defined for /user/login. there is a /user/edit end point. Am I correct to assume that /user/login?_format=json POST is set up by default?

Any help with this would be mightily appreciated.

I retried the ajax request and saw that it is a "cors" related issue. Still, I don't see why it is a problem. I'm including my "cors" configuration from the services.yml file on my site. In my experience this should enable POST requests from within browser. Unless I'm missing something...

```
   cors.config:
enabled: true
allowedHeaders:
  [
    "x-csrf-token",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "accept",
    "origin",
    "x-requested-with",
    "access-control-allow-origin",
    "x-allowed-header",
    "*",
  ]
allowedMethods: ["*"]
allowedOrigins: ["*"]
exposedHeaders: false
maxAge: false
supportsCredentials: true
```

Also here is the latest fetch request I'm using. It's not that different from the other one.

```
  _handleSubmit = async event => {
event.preventDefault();
const response = await fetch(
  "http://example.com/user/login?_format=json",
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
      user: "myname",
      pass: "mypassword"
    })
  }
);
console.log(response);
```

};

Comment: The url is different in the curl vs the fetch that you posted..

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185494/user-login-rest-format

Comment: Oh you're right. I actually used the same one in both cases. "edit/user" is the endpoint shown in the REST UI module though so I plugged that in at one point and I guess copied that accidentally into the question.

Comment: Yeah. THAT ^ question is where I got the Curl example. But it DOESN"T work when I submit a fetch or axios request using the exact same parameters. I think there is a bug in the REST module.

Comment: More info: it has something to do with cors, maybe. The response header is: type: "cors"
url: "http://adminflambeau.com/user/login?_format=json"
redirected: false
status: 500
ok: false
statusText: "500 Service unavailable (with message)"  - But my services.yml should have that covered

Comment: cors.config:
    enabled: true
    allowedHeaders:
      [
        "x-csrf-token",
        "authorization",
        "content-type",
        "accept",
        "origin",
        "x-requested-with",
        "access-control-allow-origin",
        "x-allowed-header",
        "*",
      ]
    allowedMethods: ["*"]
    allowedOrigins: ["*"]
    exposedHeaders: false
    maxAge: false
    supportsCredentials: true        <--- (services.yml cors setup)

Comment: Use the Network pane in browser devtools to examine the requests and responses. What’s the HTTP method of the request for which the server’s responding with a 500 error? Is it a POST request or is it an OPTIONS request?

Comment: @sideshowbarker - I figured out a solve which I am posting below. I appreciate the comments above from everyone. Sorry I don't really know exactly what the problem was but since I found a working solution (maybe not THE solution?) I'm just going with that.

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty everybody.... I got it to work. IDK if other people have come up against this but using Postman I was able to extract a fetch configuration which didn't run up against a "cors" 500 error. So I will post the solution below after the following notices:

1 - For now I ditched "await" syntax as the Promise constructed by Postman "just worked".
2 - The response delivers the CSRF token very nicely, but I haven't captured the token and used it for CRUD GETs or POSTs, etc. If it works great. If not I'll have to diddle around with session cookies or JWTs or who-knows-what-all.

In other words I'm just happy I got a response and am sharing my solution.

3 - Before this solve at certain points I was able to get a 200 response with an empty body. But I did notice (and you will too) that Postman added something I didn't have before... "redirect: "follow". I'm thinking that was the key here.

Well here it is for those who might be struggling, or laughing at my ignorance...

```
_handleSubmit = async event => {
event.preventDefault();
const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
const body = JSON.stringify({ name: "myname", pass: "myPW" });
const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: body,
  redirect: "follow"
};
fetch("http://example.com/user/login?_format=json", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log("error", error)); };
```